# How to search for a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

How does one find facts about a given graph one has in mind?

For example, how would I find out if the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) is already known if I stumbled upon it while searching for a counterexample for something?

Is there an OEIS-like search engine which accepts adjacency matrices or a similar graph representation?

Comment: A quick search came up with this: https://hog.grinvin.org/

Comment: Thank you! I actually visited the link on [The Encyclopedia of Graphs](http://atlas.gregas.eu/sources) pointing to the site, but it was to a subpage from which the existence of a search engine is not apparent.